# Can I generating route helper methods dynamically in a view helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm refactoring some view code into a helper method, and I'm wondering if I can simplify it further.

```
# In the view...

<%= navigation_link params[:controller], 'accounts', account_path %>

# ApplicationHelper

def navigation_link(controller_name, page_name, path_name)
  if controller_name == page_name
    content_tag :li, "#{page_name.capitalize.singularize}", :class => 'current'
  else
    content_tag :li, link_to("#{page_name.capitalize.singularize}", path_name)
  end
end
```

Passing the string 'accounts' along with the route helper method name account_path seems redundant.

Do I really need to pass in the third argument path_name, or can I generate that in the navigation_link helper with the string I pass in as the second argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use Object#send.

```
# The view simplifies to this...

<%= navigation_link params[:controller], 'accounts' %>

# ...and the ApplicationHelper becomes...

def navigation_link(controller_name, page_name)
  if controller_name == page_name
    content_tag :li, "#{page_name.capitalize.singularize}", :class => 'current'
  else
    content_tag :li, link_to("#{page_name.capitalize.singularize}", send("#{page_name.singularize}_path")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess your helper is already a part of Rails. It's called [`link_to_unless_current`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current) (clickable)

Example:

```
<li><%= link_to_unless_current("Home", { :action => "index" }) %></li>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was asking, but that's a pretty nifty helper and gets me 80% there. Is there any way to pass a conditional class name, so that I can style my current <li> elements different from the others?

Comment: @Bob, you can pass in a block to this method where you can specify how the element should be rendered if it is not current. class is one of the html options, of course.

Comment: I can swear that there was author's comment that he managed it with styling `li` and additional style for `li a`. This should work.